# Angular nvd3 multichart with focus

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

did any one have any idea how to add a focus line to angular nvd3 multichart?
here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YSYK9p?p=preview) with `focusEnable:true` but not working
thank you in advance